# psycopg2のインストールが、VisualStudioのコンパイルエラーC2491で終了してしまう

Tags: python, windows, postgresql

Herokuを使っているのですが、`Windows7`にて、

```
C:\Users\dragonball\heroku\okinta>pip install -r requirements.txt
```

をすると、以下のエラーが出てきて、どうしていいか分かりません。どのようにすればいいのかアドバイス頂けないでしょうか？

```
C:\Users\dragonball\heroku\okinta>pip install -r requirements.txt

Collecting dj-database-url==0.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Collecting Django==1.9.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached Django-1.9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting gunicorn==19.4.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached gunicorn-19.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psycopg2==2.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz
Collecting whitenoise==2.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached whitenoise-2.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests==2.9.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Using cached requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django-debug-toolbar==1.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Using cached django_debug_toolbar-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting sqlparse (from django-debug-toolbar==1.4->-r requirements.txt (line 7
))
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psycopg2 ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\pyt
hon35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hide
ry\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-popk09j9\\psycopg2\\setup.py';exec(compile(g
etattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\dragonball\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcssofwgzpip-whee
l- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\errorcodes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\extensions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\extras.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\pool.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\psycopg1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\tz.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\_json.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\_range.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\dbapi20.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\dbapi20_tpc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\testconfig.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\testutils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_async.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_bugX000.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_bug_gc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_cancel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_connection.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_copy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_cursor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_dates.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_green.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_lobject.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_module.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_notify.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_quote.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_transaction.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_types_basic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_types_extras.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\test_with.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  copying tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
  Skipping optional fixer: buffer
  Skipping optional fixer: idioms
  Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\psycopg
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3
 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=\"2.6.1 (dt
dec pq3 ext)\"" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090504 -Ic:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\progra
ms\python\python35-32\include -Ic:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\py
thon35-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/9.5/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/
9.5/include/server "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE"
"-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Fil
es\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\include
\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcpsycopg\psycopgmodul
e.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\psycopg\psycopgmodule.obj
  psycopgmodule.c
  .\psycopg/config.h(134): warning C4005: 'isnan': macro redefinition
  C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(264): note:
see previous definition of 'isnan'
  .\psycopg/config.h(138): warning C4005: 'isinf': macro redefinition
  C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(263): note:
see previous definition of 'isinf'
  .\psycopg/config.h(150): error C2491: 'round': definition of dllimport functio
n not allowed
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.e
xe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installing collected packages: dj-database-url, Django, gunicorn, psycopg2, whit
enoise, requests, sqlparse, django-debug-toolbar
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\p
ython35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hi
dery\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-popk09j9\\psycopg2\\setup.py';exec(compile
(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file_
_, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\dragonball\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pls65_zx-re
cord\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\errorcodes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\extensions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\extras.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\pool.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\psycopg1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\tz.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\_json.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\_range.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\dbapi20.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\dbapi20_tpc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\testconfig.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\testutils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_async.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_bugX000.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_bug_gc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_cancel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_connection.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_copy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_cursor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_dates.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\test
s
    copying tests\test_green.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_lobject.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_module.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_notify.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests

    copying tests\test_quote.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_transaction.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_types_basic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_types_extras.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\test_with.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    copying tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\psycopg2\tests
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\psycopg
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /
W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=\"2.6.1 (d
t dec pq3 ext)\"" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090504 -Ic:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\prog
rams\python\python35-32\include -Ic:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\
python35-32\include -I. -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/9.5/include -IC:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~
1/9.5/include/server "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE
" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program F
iles\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\inclu
de\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcpsycopg\psycopgmod
ule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\psycopg\psycopgmodule.obj
    psycopgmodule.c
    .\psycopg/config.h(134): warning C4005: 'isnan': macro redefinition
    C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(264): note
: see previous definition of 'isnan'
    .\psycopg/config.h(138): warning C4005: 'isinf': macro redefinition
    C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(263): note
: see previous definition of 'isinf'
    .\psycopg/config.h(150): error C2491: 'round': definition of dllimport funct
ion not allowed
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl
.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\req\req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\req\req_install.py", line 880, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 718, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\program
s\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\
\Users\\dragonball\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-popk09j9\\psycopg2\\setup.py';ex
ec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'
), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\dragonball\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-p
ls65_zx-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile"
 failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\dragonball\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-popk09
j9\psycopg2\

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\commands\install.py", line 350, in run
    requirement_set.cleanup_files()
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\utils\build.py", line 38, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\utils\build.py", line 42, in cleanup
    rmtree(self.name)
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 102, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py"
, line 488, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py"
, line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py"
, line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py"
, line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py"
, line 378, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py"
, line 387, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\users\dragonball\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler
    func(path)
OSError: [WinError 145] ディレクトリが空ではありません。: 'C:\\Users\\dragonball\\Ap
pData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-popk09j9\\Django\\django\\views\\decorators'
```

参考として、

```
C:\Users\dragonball\heroku\okinta>more requirements.txt
dj-database-url==0.4.0
Django==1.9.2
gunicorn==19.4.5
psycopg2==2.6.1
whitenoise==2.0.6
requests==2.9.1
django-debug-toolbar==1.4

C:\Users\dragonball\heroku\okinta>python -V
Python 3.5.1

C:\Users\dragonball\heroku\okinta>psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.4
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku上ではなくてローカルのWindows環境でインストールするときの話ですね？

```
    psycopgmodule.c
    .\psycopg/config.h(134): warning C4005: 'isnan': macro redefinition
    C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(264): note
: see previous definition of 'isnan'
    .\psycopg/config.h(138): warning C4005: 'isinf': macro redefinition
    C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(263): note
: see previous definition of 'isinf'
    .\psycopg/config.h(150): error C2491: 'round': definition of dllimport funct
ion not allowed
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl
.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

このあたりのキーワードで検索してみると、VS2015環境で同様のエラーが発生するという報告が見つかりました。psycopg側で用意していた関数・マクロがVSに付属するようになってしまって競合している、という話のようです。

https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/393

で、この問題は [Psycopg 2.6.2](http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2016/07/07/psycopg-262-released/) で修正済みとのことですから、2.6.1から2.6.2に乗り換えるのが手っ取り早いかと思います。

Comment: ♦さん　ご回答まことにありがとうございます。今手元に問題のパソコンがないため、後で試させて頂きます。取り急ぎ感謝の意を述べさせていただきます。

Comment: ありがとうございました。確かにバージョン依存の問題だったようです。